# Transformation laws for tensors on general manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, tensors

I was interested in tensor products rather from the mathematical, abstract point of view, so topics like various tensor products in the context of, for example, Banach spaces, $C^*$-algebras and so on. However I'm not skilled in manipulating with tensors: especially I'm interested what happens with the tensor after changing coordinates. I mean by this the following context: let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $u$ be some tensor field of type $(r,s)$: this means that for a point $x \in M$, $u_x$ is an element of $T_x(M) \otimes T_x(M) \otimes... \otimes T_x(M) \otimes T^*_x(M) \otimes ... \otimes T^*_x(M)$ where $T_x$ appears $r$-times and $T^*_x(M)$ appears $s$ times. This can locally be expressed as $\sum u^{i_1,...,i_r}_{j_1,...,j_s}\partial_{i_1} \otimes ... \otimes \partial_{i_r} \otimes dx^{j_1} \otimes ... \otimes dx^{j_r}$ (this means that there is some chart $\varphi:U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ $\varphi=(x^1,...,x^n)$ where $U \subset M$ is some open set and $\partial_{i_k}$ are the canonical vector fields associated with this chart). Now suppose that $\psi:V \to \mathbb{R}^n, \psi=(y^1,...,y^n)$ is another chart with $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$. I would like to know how the tensor $u$ express in this new coordinates: of course I met some formulas, but I'm afraid that these formulas didn't take the charts into account (and moreover I'm pretty sure that some expressions in the formulas don't make sense when read literally and guessing what author really meant is not a good idea). I would be happy with only giving me a precise reference for a formulas provided that they are carefully written.